# What does it mean by "loops and troughs"?

Tags: metallurgy, chemistry

Actually, I've asked this question in "English Language & Usage" but someone told me ask it here!

What does it mean by "loops and troughs" in:
"Source has acquired a pattern of loops and troughs."

Here's some context including this phrase: https://books.google.com/books?id=a6LzCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=%22loops+and+troughs%22&source=bl&ots=0M9eK7xYHc&sig=afrE7rVYxX8Zxda7_L7NDGYWzYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhk4Cqz8HZAhUKZ1AKHSFnBsEQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=%22loops%20and%20troughs%22&f=false

Comment: what makes you think there is some deeper meaning than the term the author used to describe his observation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever looked at finger prints? Many finger prints have patterns of loops & troughs - though for finger prints the troughs may be called arches. It's just a description of a pattern.

Get a rubber band and change its shape any way you like and it forms all forms of loops. Break the rubber band to create a rubber string and change its shape and you will get different forms of troughs and arches.